# iphone vibrate multiple time when detect proximity sensor but only once

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have develope one app in that app i am working on proximity sensor detection. And when proximity detect make vibrate a phone. It's run successfully but when second time open that app and detect proximity phone not vibrate condition execute both first and second time. i am confuse now please help me to do this.

below code i have been used.

```
if([[delegate.vibrationdefault stringForKey:@"Vibration"] isEqualToString:@"on"])
{
    NSLog(@"Proximity detect with vibration on") ;
    [recorder stop];
    //AudioServicesPlayalSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) ;
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) ;
    [recorder record];
}
```

Comment: so does this mean that you have to vibrate only once but it is vibrating twice ? Is that your question?

Comment: no i want to vibrate many times..

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure that this will work fine, but you can maybe do like this:

```
if([[delegate.vibrationdefault stringForKey:@"Vibration"] isEqualToString:@"on"])
{
    NSLog(@"Proximity detect with vibration on") ;
    [recorder stop];
    //AudioServicesPlayalSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) ;
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) ;
    sleep(1);
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) ;
    sleep(1);
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) ;
    [recorder record];
}
```

You can use the `sleep(timeInSeconds);` under to delay it. I'm not sure if you could use 0.5 seconds, but you can try it.

Comment: this is not my requirement i want whwn user second time launch app this case execute.. but my phone not vibrate.